# Picklist type inline editing in lightning:dataTable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-datatable

I have a situation where I need to edit contents of lightning:dataTable and editing should be done from a picklist and not from edit box.

I have seen many examples where custom inline Editors are created and custom data table is created nut is there a way to do it using `<lightning:dataTable>`

My code is :

.cmp file :

```
 <lightning:dataTable aura:id="Tree" columns="{!v.gridColumns}" data="{!v.gridData}" keyField="id"  hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
```

.js code

```
        var Columns = [
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'text',
            label: 'Name'
        },
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'type',
            label: 'Type'
        }    
    ];

    component.set('v.gridColumns', Columns);
```

I want Name column to be editable and it should pick values from a dropdown/picklist.

adding `editable:'true'` will make it as editable but it will be textbox editable

Answer (score 4):

Not possible. Picklist isn't an available data type in lightning:datatable. You would need to implement your own custom data table if you wanted to have this feature available.